# how to deselect a row in ListFragment

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I have the following code which displays a ListFragment. Once a row is selected i turn the row's background to red. If i click another row then that turns red but the first selected row remains red.

How can i turn the colour back for the deselected rows? I've tried a few things like, clearCoices(), list.invalidate(), list.requestLayout(), list.refreshDrawableState. None of them seem to work.

Thanks in advance, Matt

```
public  class CarerDetailsFragment extends ListFragment{

    private static final String TAG = CarerDetailsFragment.class.getSimpleName();
     MySimpleArrayAdapter myAdapter;
     TwoDimensionalArrayList rotaArray;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle b = getArguments();

        if(b != null){

        rotaArray = (TwoDimensionalArrayList) b.get("rotaArray");

        Log.e(TAG, "rotaArray in CarerDetailsFragment has size " + rotaArray.size());

        }else{

            Log.e(TAG, "Bundle b = null!!!!!!!!!!!");

        }

    }








    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.carerdetailsfragmentlayout, container, false);
    }








    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        myAdapter = (MySimpleArrayAdapter) new MySimpleArrayAdapter(getActivity(), rotaArray);

        setListAdapter(myAdapter);


    }








    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Log.e(TAG, "onListItemClick");

        l.clearChoices();






        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));


        String name;
        String actTimeIn;
        String actTimeOut;
        String doubleUpValue;
        String status;
        String startTime;
        String clientID;
        String notes;




        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("name", name);
        b.putString("actTimeIn", actTimeIn);

        Fragment newFragment = new CarerPurposeOfCallFragment();
        newFragment.setArguments(b);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack
        transaction.replace(R.id.carerpurposeofcall, newFragment);
        //transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();




    }








    private class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private final Context context;
        private final ArrayList<?> list;

        String justTime;
        String statusField;
        String callID;
        String needName;

        public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<?> list) {

            super(context, R.layout.rotarowlayout);
            Log.e(TAG, "inside adapter constructor");
            this.context = context;
            this.list = list;

            //Log.e(TAG, "list has size of " + this.list.size());


        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rotarowlayout, parent, false);




            TextView startTime = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowstarttime);
            TextView duration = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowduration);
            TextView status = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowstatus);
            TextView name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowclientname);
            final ImageView noteStatus = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.notestatus);




            return rowView;




        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            if(this.list != null){

            return this.list.size();
            }else{
                return 0;
            }


        }



    }// end of adapter class








}//end of CarerListFragment
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `myAdapter.toggleSelection(position);` to select or unselect.
You probably need to have `selectedList` and do checks when you toggle.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, could you give an explanation please. thanks

Comment: myAdapter of type SimpleCursorAdapter doesn't seem to have a toggleSelection() method.

Comment: @turtleboy Use custom Adapter extended from BaseAdapter. That's how it's done in my app.